# how do i show the page numbers in GET format with ? in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am having a difficulty which I think must have a very simple answer.
i am using **CodeIgniter** for my project and I am using the **pagination** to show page numbers for posts

CODE

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
        if (count($_GET) > 0) $config['suffix'] = '?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
        $config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php/main/bloggers');
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_num;
        $config['per_page'] = $rec_per_page;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['reuse_query_string'] = false;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<span class='page_num'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

This code shows me the url like this

```
domain.com/index.php/main/blogger/**2**
```

where 2 is the page number which is good

**current url is like this**

> ```
> domain.com/index.php/main/blogger/**2**
> ```

**Desired url is**

> ```
> domain.com/index.php/main/blogger?**page=2**
> ```

**Question: what I want is that I want the page number to come in GET type of variable so that I can just use GET and get the value of page as if I use segment I am not sure there may be other values too some times.**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the following options on your pagination configuration array:

```
// Set the pagination to use the get parameter
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

// Set the name of the get paramater
$config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
```